# Cannot access or find reference to System.Xml.Linq.LineInfoAnnotation. Why is this?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I have an application which takes an XML document and sorts it by certain attributes. I have information associated with each line of the XML document which I want to include in the sorted document. In order to do this,

When I load the file, I make sure the line info is loaded using **XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo)**.

Then I recursively iterate over each XElement and get its line info. When I ran the app, I noticed that each XElement has two annotations,

- one of type **System.Xml.Linq.LineInfoAnnotation**
- and one of type **System.Xml.Linq.LineInfoEndElementAnnotation**.

They contain the info that I need but in private fields.

I can't find any information on these classes, I can't instantiate them, they do not appear in the Object browser under **System.Xml.Linq**. Yet they exist and I can run "GetType()" on them and get information about the class.

**If they exist, why are they not in MSDN references and why can't I instantiate them or extend them? Why can't I find them in the object browser?**

***P.S.*** My workaround for this was to use reflection to get the information contained inside each element. But I still can't pass a class name to tell the method what type it is, I have to isolate the object from XElement.Annotations(typeof(object)), and then run GetType() on it. I've illustrated this below.

```
public object GetInstanceField(Type type, object instance, string fieldName)
{
 //reflective method that gets value of private field
}

XElement xEl = existingXElement;    //existingXElement is passed in

var annotations = xEl.Annotations(typeof(object)); //contains two objects, start and end LineInfoAnnotation
var start = annotations.First(); 
var end = annotations.Last(); 

var startLineNumber = GetInstanceField(start.GetType(), start, lineNumber);  //lineNumber is private field I'm trying to access.
var endLineNumber = GetInstanceField(end.GetType(), end, lineNumber);
```

This code works, but again, I can't just tell the method "typeof(LineInfoAnnotation)", instead I have to do GetType on the existing object. I cannot make sense of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those classes are private - an implementation detail, if you will.

All XObjects (elements, attributes) implement the IXmlLineInfo interface - but they implement the inteface explicitly, so you must perform a cast to access the properties.

Once you have your IXmlLineInfo, you can use the properties [LineNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538457) and [LinePosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538364).

```
var data = 
@"<example>
<someElement
  someAttribute=""val"">

  </someElement></example>
";

var doc = XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)), LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
foreach(var element in doc.Descendants()) {
    var elLineInfo = element as IXmlLineInfo;
    Console.Out.WriteLine(
        $"Element '{element.Name}' at {elLineInfo.LineNumber}:{elLineInfo.LinePosition}");


    foreach(var attr in element.Attributes()) {
        var attrLineInfo = attr as IXmlLineInfo;
        Console.Out.WriteLine(
            $"Attribute '{attr.Name}' at {attrLineInfo.LineNumber}:{attrLineInfo.LinePosition}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Element 'example' at 1:2
Element 'someElement' at 2:2
Attribute 'someAttribute' at 3:3
```

To get the EndElement information, you have to use a plain old XML reader, since the XObject api doesn't expose any information about where the element ends.

```
using(var reader = doc.CreateReader()) {    
    while(reader.Read()) {
        var lineInfo = reader as IXmlLineInfo;
        Console.Out.WriteLine($"{reader.NodeType} {reader.Name} at {lineInfo.LineNumber}:{lineInfo.LinePosition}");

        if(reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.HasAttributes) {
            while(reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine($"{reader.NodeType} {reader.Name} at {lineInfo.LineNumber}:{lineInfo.LinePosition}");
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Element example at 1:2
Element someElement at 2:2
Attribute someAttribute at 3:3
EndElement someElement at 5:5
EndElement example at 5:19
```

Comment: I tried that at first but it did not give me the closing line number of the element, despite that the information is present. That being said, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Nodes with the the fake 'EndElement' NodeType are not exposed via the XObject API - you have to use the plain old XML reader api instead. I added an example.