# IXmlLineInfo members not available on XElement (athough implementation is there)

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

C#, .NET 6.0

Short:

`XElement` is implementing `IXmlLineInfo`. However, `IXmlLineInfo` methods are not directly available over an instance of `XElement`. Why?

Long:

`XElement` is in the inheritance/implementation tree `XElement` > `XContainer` > `XNode` > `XObject` > `IXmlLineInfo`. `IXmlLineInfo` is declaring two properties and one method. I always though that if `X` (even indirectly) implements `IX`, then, on instance of `X`, I can access all the (public) members of `IX`. However, over an instance of `XElement`, those members of `IXmlLineInfo` are not available. I have to cast `XElement` to `IXmlLineInfo` to access the members.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\doc.xml");
XElement root = doc.Root!;
IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = root;

int a = lineInfo.LineNumber;  // works correctly
int b = root.LineNumber;      // throws a syntax error - why, as the underlying object is the same?
```

Why are not members of `IXmlLineInfo` available directly? What am I missing?

Comment: `IXmlLineInfo` is [explicitly implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) by `XObject`.

Comment: OK to close as a dup of [Cannot access or find reference to System.Xml.Linq.LineInfoAnnotation. Why is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49698494) then?  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698549) by gnud states, *All XObjects (elements, attributes) implement the IXmlLineInfo interface - but they implement the inteface explicitly, so you must perform a cast to access the properties* and so also seems to answer your question.